# How to merge menu with WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu

The default MVVP [I have seen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) has multiple ViewModel objects that are rendered through data templates.  Each ViewModel exposes commands via their own properties.

I would like to merge ViewModel commands with the menu so when different tabs are selected, the menu changes based on what the ViewModel does.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-infrastructure-activeawarecommand.html) provides a good framework for doing this.